# What does the frequency of my miner mean?

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration

What does the clock frequency of my miner mean. I can change it but how does it affect performance? For BFGMiner when I start my Gridseed I can press 'C' to change it.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific config file parameter, like `–bmsc-freq`? If so, you should add it to your question. Adding more detail to your question would be appreciated, and would be more helpful to others who might have the same question.

Comment: No the clock frequency. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is just a parameter to allow you to control the clock frequency (usually measured in MHz) of your miner. You can see a sample list of configurations for CGMiner [here](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/README).

There is an inherent trade-off here. A higher frequency means a higher hash-rate but more energy consumption and wear-and-tear on your hardware. For example, [this site](http://bitcoinrigs.org/instructions/antminer-u1/) shows a sample chart of different frequencies and hash rates for a particular piece of hardware. It's up to individual miners to figure out what the right trade-off between performance and energy consumption is for them.